# Recommendations on third party libs/components for printing from Windows service

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, service, printing

We've been struggling with printing from an ASP .NET application lately, after upgrading to Windows Server 2008 R2. We have a printer control which uses System.Drawing.Printing along with ReportViewer to print RDLC reports to printers connected to the server.

We've learnt that System.Drawing.Printing doesn't support non-GUI applications, such as services or application running in a service context. In fact .NET doesn't seem to support printing from a service at all.

*Are there any third party components you would recommend as a replacement for our System.Drawing.Printing implementation?*

This could be either a library/component we would use in our ASP .NET application or a separate service running on the server with an API for handling print requests, e.g. an RDLC report.